# How to getDefaultModelObject without submit form Wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have some checkgroup ,can i getDefaultModelObject  without submit form i need checked checkbox thank you ,sorry my enlish not good

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from your question, but if what you want is to get notified of checkbox changes, and have the `CheckGroup`'s modelobject updated at every change, use an [`AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.html).

```
CheckGroup cg = new CheckGroup("id");
cg.add(new Radio("id1", someObject);    
cg.add(new Radio("id2", someObject2);
cg.add(new Radio("id3", someObject3);
cg.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior(){
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // Get the CheckGroup's updated model object.
        Object modelObject = getComponent().getModelObject(); 
    } 
};
```

This component will output proper javascript event listeners on all your `<input type="check">` or `<input type="radio">` in order to call the `onUpdate` method of the behavior.

Take into account that `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` will execute `Validators` for the component (and call `onError` instead of `onUpdate` accordingly), but *it won't* execute FormValidators, so you'll have to check the input for yourself if that's the case.